# Priority btween Location and LocationMatch in apache2.conf

Tags: apache2

I have this line in apache, before others

```
<LocationMatch "\.\.;">
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule .* / [L,R=403]
</LocationMatch>
```

I am trying to avoid the problem mentioned here: https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/tomcat-path-traversal-via-reverse-proxy-mapping/

The problem is that some of the directives like this one are no longer exposing this issue:

```
<Location "/AXIS/">
        ProxyPass ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/AXIS/
        ProxyPassReverse ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/AXIS/
</Location>
```

but others do manifest the same problem just like my rule is ignored. Some examples:

```
<Location "/WS/">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{ENV:X_SESSIONREF} (.+)
        RewriteRule . - [E=SREF:%1,NS]
        RequestHeader set X_SESSIONREF "%{SREF}e" env=SREF
        RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
        RewriteRule . - [E=RU2:%1,NS]
        RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER "%{RU2}e" env=RU2

        ProxyPass ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/WS/
        ProxyPassReverse ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/WS/
</Location>

<Location "/rest/">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{ENV:X_SESSIONREF} (.+)
        RewriteRule . - [E=SREF:%1,NS]
        RequestHeader set X_SESSIONREF "%{SREF}e" env=SREF
        RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
        RewriteRule . - [E=RU2:%1,NS]
        RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER "%{RU2}e" env=RU2
        RewriteCond %{ENV:X_SESSION} (.+)
        RewriteRule . - [E=ASSESS:%1,NS]
        RequestHeader set X_SESSION "%{ASSESS}e" env=ASSESS

        ProxyPass ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/rest/
        ProxyPassReverse ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/rest/

        ErrorDocument 403 default
        ErrorDocument 404 default
        ErrorDocument 405 default
        ErrorDocument 406 default
        ErrorDocument 409 default
        ErrorDocument 500 default
        ErrorDocument 502 default
        ErrorDocument 503 default

</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the directives in apache configuration files are read like the files are included : this mean the last pick (file beginning with "z") is the one loaded.

Could you try to put the directives which are now avoid at the end of the config files lastly included ? It should overload the firstly encountered according the documentation :

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#related